# How can I get the stacktrace from a Crashlytics report?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics on my app, but the server team wants me to send the crash to them as well... I can't use Crashlytics Webhooks system because the server is not willing to change their implementation to accomodate Crashlytics requirements.

So I'm trying to grab the report before it is being sent, and send it to the server as well. I'm trying to use the `CrashlyticsDelegate` with the `crashlyticsDidDetectReport` method. But it looks like the `CLSReport` doesn't actually have a property for the crash itself... only some basic information like identifier, bundleversion, crashdate and stuff like that... Am I missing something? Is there a way I can get an actual copy of the stacktrace so I can resend it somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used to work on the Crashlytics SDK.

It's been a while, but it wasn't possible at that time. The Crashlytics report is in a format that isn't really feasible for a 3rd party to read and make sense of. If you poke around in your app's sandbox directory, you can find the data. And it is more-or-less human-readable. But, it's complex, and built with a format that's difficult to work with. What's more, the stack trace the SDK captures is just addresses. Symbolication is almost entirely done server-side.

If this is a hard requirement for you, you may need to look into another reporting service. It should be possible to have two exist simultaneously. Though I would not recommend it, as the crash reporting facilities are per-process and it is hard to guarantee SDK interoperability.

However, I'd also recommend reaching out to their support people. They are good, and also likely have more up-to-date information than I do.